# What is the probability of drawing the same combination twice?

Tags: probability

Maths noob, here.

I have a set of 100 distinct words, and I randomly select three words to form a combination, like *happy.tire.complain*.

The combination must comprise of three distinct words - so combinations like *happy.tire.happy*, for example, are ineligible.

I do this twice, to form two random combinations. What is the probability that the two combinations will be identical?

Intuition leads me to this working, but I feel like it's wrong:

**1.** P(1) * P(2) * P(3) = (1/100) * (1/99) * (1/98) = 1/970200 = x

**2.** P(4) * P(5) * P(6) = (1/100) * (1/99) * (1/98) = 1/970200 = y

**3.** x * y =  1/970200² = 1/941288040000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$100\cdot 99\cdot 98$$ choices for the three words (assuming that the order matters), so the probability to get the same word in the second try is just $$\frac{1}{100\cdot 99\cdot 98}$$